# How to reduce memory usage in xarray multidimensional rolling aggregation?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-xarray, rolling-computation

Given a multidimensional xarray DataArray, I would like to perform multidimensional rolling aggregation.  For example, if I have a DataArray that is m x n x k, I would like to be able to roll the data along the m axis, and aggregate away either the n or k dimension.

I have an approach that gives me the correct answer but seems not to scale at all.  If my window sizes are small, it is feasible, but in the case of a 5000 x 2000 x 10 DataArray, rolling along the 5000 length dimension with a long window explodes memory with my current approach.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

drange = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', freq='D', periods=5000)
x = ['x%i' % i for i in range(1, 3001)]
y = ['y%i' % i for i in range(1,11)]
raw_dat = np.random.randn(len(drange), len(x), len(y))
da = xr.DataArray(raw_dat, coords={'time': drange, 'x': x, 'y': y}, dims=['time', 'x', 'y'])

new_da = da.rolling(time=20).construct('window_dim')
final_da = new_da.stack(combo=['x', 'window_dim']).std('combo')
```

I have also tried the below, it gives the same result but also runs out of memory when the rolling window is large.

```
new_da = da.rolling(time=20).construct('window_dim')
final_da = new_da.std(['x', 'window_dim'])
```

The above code works and on my machine takes roughly 35 seconds to perform the stack and aggregation, but as window size increases, memory usage explodes.  I am wondering if there is a smarter way to do this type of aggregation.